# Referencing external modules in application types declarations

Tags: typescript

How can I get a reference an external module in my application declaration file? Please look at following example:

```javascript
// file meteor.d.ts
declare module "meteor/meteor" {
  export module Meteor {
  ...
  }
}

// file context.d.ts
// not part of any module

declare interface IContext {
  Meteor: typeof Meteor; // how do I get the referwence to Meteor?
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I get the reference to Meteor?

You can't at the moment. Not without changing the `meteor.d.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for double posting.

Comment: @tomitrescak not at all. This question does belong here as a Question. And does belong there as a Request 

Comment: For other people that arrive here, there is a possible way to do this : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7352#issuecomment-191547232 but I don't recommend it.